# Using an interface to create generic code for 2 database models in mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am attempting to add an interface to make generic code for 2 database repository models, however in each database model returns a different type and I have been unable to find a solution. This seems like it should be possible but I am out of ideas can anybody point me in the right direction or tell me if it is not possible.

Code - Interface:

```
interface IPermissions
{
    //List<User> getUser(string userID);
    List<Role> getUserPermissions(string userName);
    List<Role> getAllPermissions();
    void enable();
    void disable();
    void addPermission(string permissionName);
    void removePermission(string permissionName);
}
```

Model 1:

```
public List<AUser> getUser(string userName)
{
    IEnumerable<AUser> users = from x in a.AUsers
                                    where x.UserID == userName
                                    select x;

    List<AUser> usersList = users.ToList();
    return usersList;
}

public List<AGroup> getUserPermissions(string userName)
{
    IEnumerable<AGroup> usersPermisions = from abfug in a.UserGroups
                                              join abfg in a.Group on abfug.GroupID equals abfg.ID
                                              join au in a.AUsers on abfug.UserID equals au.ID
                                              where au.UserID == userName
                                              select abfg;

    List<Group> usersList = usersPermisions.ToList();
    return usersList;
}
```

Model 2:

```
public List<UCUser> getUCUser(string userName)
{
    IEnumerable<UCsUser> users = from y in UC.UCUsers
                                     where y.UserID == userName
                                     select y;

    List<UCyUser> usersList = users.ToList();
    return usersList;
}

public List<UCGroup> getUCUserPermissions(string userName)
{
    IEnumerable<UCGroup> userPermissions = from bfug in UC.UCUserGroups
                                               join bfg in UC.UCGroups on bfug.GroupID equals bfg.ID
                                               join u in UC.UCUsers on bfug.UserID equals u.ID
                                               where u.UserID == userName
                                               select bfg;

    List<UCGroup> usersList = userPermissions.ToList();
    return usersList;
}
```

If there are any typos in the code please bear with me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're looking at using the repository pattern, look at the answer I give [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25571794/how-to-remove-dbset-from-my-interface/25571905#25571905) for advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a generic pattern, you make the interface generic:

```
public interface IRepository<TModel>
{
    IEnumerable<TModel> Retrieve();

    void Create(TModel model);
    void Delete(TModel model);
    void Update(TModel model);
}

public class RoleRepository : IRepository<Role>
{
    IEnumerable<TModel> Retrieve()
    {
        using (var context = new MyContext())
        {

            return context.Roles.ToList(); // iterating through them hits the database
        }
    }

    public void Create(TModel model)
    {
        using (var context = new MyContext())
        {
            context.Set<TModel>().Attach(model);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    public void Delete(TModel model) {}
    public void Update(TModel model) {}
}

public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRepository<Role> roleRepository;

    public MyController(IRepository<Role> roleRepository)
    {
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
    }
}
```

Once you have this, you will generally hide this behind a service. Then you have proper serparation of concerns. The repository layer hides the context, so that can change easily. The service layer hides the repository so that can change easily, also you can add those operation specific functions to the service.

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly IRepository<Role> roleRepository;

    public MyService(IRepository<Role> roleRepository)
    {
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Role> LetsDoSomeCoolThings()
    {
        // some complicated role specific function to return a complex set of results
    }
}
```

Now obviously you would then substitute the `Repository` in the controller for this service